# не работает table-valued function

Tags: sql-server

Использовал базу `AdventureWorks2012`
написал такую функцию

```
Alter FUNCTION [Person].GetSimiliarEmail
(@3_letter nvarchar, @NumberOfOrders int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT   [BusinessEntityID]
      ,[EmailAddressID]
      ,[EmailAddress]
      ,[rowguid]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
       FROM [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[EmailAddress] as e
       WHERE convert(nvarchar, left(e.EmailAddress,3)) = @3_letter
 );
GO
```

запрос

```
select* FROM [Person].GetSimiliarEmail('ken')
```

НЕ возвращает ни единого значения
а запрос

```
SELECT* FROM [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[EmailAddress] as e
WHERE convert(nvarchar, left(e.EmailAddress,3)) = 'ken'
```

возвращает кучу
Что я некорректно написал в table-valued function?

Comment: так у функции определено 2 параметра, а передаётся только один `select* FROM [Person].GetSimiliarEmail('ken')`

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто, я забыл указать количество знаков в nvarchar,
надо было написать  @3_letter nvarchar **(3)**